# how to remove error in mosquitto installation

Tags: linux, mosquitto

**i'm trying to install mosquitto-1.3 in Linux, for doing this follow he step.**

```
1-    wget http://mosquitto.org/files/source/mosquitto-1.3.tar.gz
2-    tar -zxvf mosquitto-1.3.tar.gz
3-    cd mosquitto-1.3
4-    cmake .
5-    make install
```

Then it start fine but in the mid it breaks and show an error.

```
  [root@localhost mosquitto-1.3]# make install 
  Scanning dependencies of target libmosquitto<br/>
  [  2%] Building C object lib/CMakeFiles/libmosquitto.dir/logging_mosq.c.o<br/>
  [  4%] Building C object lib/CMakeFiles/libmosquitto.dir/memory_mosq.c.o<br/>
  [  6%] Building C object lib/CMakeFiles/libmosquitto.dir/messages_mosq.c.o<br/>
  [  8%] Building C object lib/CMakeFiles/libmosquitto.dir/mosquitto.c.o<br/>
  [ 10%] Building C object lib/CMakeFiles/libmosquitto.dir/net_mosq.c.o<br/>
  [ 13%] Building C object lib/CMakeFiles/libmosquitto.dir/read_handle.c.o<br/>
  [ 15%] Building C object lib/CMakeFiles/libmosquitto.dir    /read_handle_client.c.o<br/>
  [ 17%] Building C object lib/CMakeFiles/libmosquitto.dir /read_handle_shared.c.o<br/>
  [ 19%] Building C object lib/CMakeFiles/libmosquitto.dir/send_client_mosq.c.o<br/>
  [ 21%] Building C object lib/CMakeFiles/libmosquitto.dir/send_mosq.c.o<br/>
  [ 23%] Building C object lib/CMakeFiles/libmosquitto.dir/srv_mosq.c.o<br/>
  [ 26%] Building C object lib/CMakeFiles/libmosquitto.dir/thread_mosq.c.o<br/>
  [ 28%] Building C object lib/CMakeFiles/libmosquitto.dir/time_mosq.c.o<br/>
  [ 30%] Building C object lib/CMakeFiles/libmosquitto.dir/tls_mosq.c.o<br/>
  [ 32%] Building C object lib/CMakeFiles/libmosquitto.dir/util_mosq.c.o<br/>
  [ 34%] Building C object lib/CMakeFiles/libmosquitto.dir/will_mosq.c.o<br/>
  Linking C shared library libmosquitto.so<br/>
  /usr/bin/ld: cannot find -lcares<br/>
  collect2: ld returned 1 exit status<br/>
  make[2]: *** [lib/libmosquitto.so.1.3] Error 1<br/>
  make[1]: *** [lib/CMakeFiles/libmosquitto.dir/all] Error 2<br/>
  make: *** [all] Error 2<br/>
```

What can i do with this... help me... Thanks.

Comment: if u http://stackoverflow.com/users/1308632/mayur can then please help me in this http://stackoverflow.com/questions/32007807/what-is-the-size-of-coap-packet my another question

Answer (score 1):

Looks like you don't have **c-ares** installed on your system. Please refer to **compiling.txt** file in source tree.

```
The following packages are required for mosquitto:

* tcp-wrappers (optional, package name libwrap0-dev)
* openssl (version 1.0.0 or greater if TLS-PSK support is needed, can be disabled)
* c-ares (for DNS-SRV support, can be disabled)
* libuuid (from e2fsprogs, can be disabled)
* On Windows, the Redhat pthreads library is required if threading support is
  to be included.

To compile, run "make", but also see the file config.mk for more details on the
various options that can be compiled in.

Where possible use the Makefiles to compile. This is particularly relevant for
the client libraries as symbol information will be included.  Use cmake to
compile on Windows or Mac.

If you have any questions, problems or suggestions (particularly related to
installing on a more unusual device like a plug-computer) then please get in
touch using the details in readme.txt.
```